# ARDUINO: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, pointers, arduino

i get this error when I run this code . The code is supposed to run a servo motor when i press a button.It uses serial data from an hc05 module to run the servo motor .I don't know c++ so I can't add anything else.The problem is in the t variable in the serial.Read() funciton i think.Thank you for your help

```
#include <Servo.h> 

Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo
int pos = 0;  // variable to store the servo position
char t;
void setup() 
{
  myservo.attach(10);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // attaches the servo on pin 10 to the servo object
     
}

void loop() 
{
  if(Serial.available()){
    t= Serial.read();
    Serial.println(t);
  }
  if(t=="O"){
    forward();
    delay(750);
    backward();
  }
  // sweeps from 0 degrees to 180 degrees
  //forward();
  //delay(1000);
  //backward();
  //delay(1000);
  // sweeps from 180 degrees to 0 degrees

}


void forward(){
    for(pos = 0; pos <= 90; pos += 1) 
  {
    myservo.write(pos);
    delay(15);
  }
}
void backward(){
    for(pos = 90; pos>=0; pos-=1)
  {
    myservo.write(pos);
    delay(15);
  }
}
```

Comment: "0" is a string literal of the type char[2] decays to char*. Chars are coded as '0' for zero char or `'\0'` for the null terminator or just 0 for the null terminator.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The condition `t=="O"` is wrong. Double quotations `""` is used for representing (c-style) strings, which are sequences of characters terminated by a null-character. It is an array and it can be converted to a pointer to the first element.

You should use single quotations `''` to represent a character constant like `t=='O'`.

Comment: I will try one second

Comment: @adham here on SO it is customary to express your gratitude in form of upvote/acceptance of the answer, rather than "thank you" comments.

Comment: Should i disconnect the hc05 module when i am uploading